# insert images buttons in tabpane and tackpane

Tags: javafx

I have created a simple tabpane which is using two tabs one has the menu the other one does have the simple game. My question or rather problem is that i am using stackPane. When I use it for my second tab it over layers the buttons. Also I cannot add a simple picture which is weird. I am using javafx

any code example would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking a question here, always provide sample code pertaining to the question and include a list of solutions you've already tried

Comment: is there a way i can send u the code

Comment: You should edit your question to include code that illustrates the problem. Do not post your entire project, but create a simple, complete example that is just enough to show the issue. Read through some of the help pages on asking questions if this is not clear: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve are good places to start.